# Set webhook for incoming messages on Twilio-Whatsapp phone number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have a Twilio phone number that's Whatsapp-capable.
When trying to programmatically set the webhook for incoming messages, the webhook is correctly set but messages are not coming through.

It appears that the webhook for Whatsapp phone number lives in a different place than the one for normal phone numbers.

To manually fix this we had to go into the Twilio console -> Programmable SMS -> Whatsapp -> Senders -> select our phone number -> paste the webhook URL and save.

So the question is: is there a way to programmatically (Twilio API) set the webhook for Whatsapp phone number?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I checked with the team and unfortunately, setting the webhook URL programmatically is not possible right now. The console is the only place to do it today.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I was wondering if an update was made to the Twilio API in order to programmatically update the webhook URL of a WhatsApp sender. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to say there were no updates in this regard. Sorry. :/

Comment: Hi Stefan, checking in again to see if setting the webhook URL for a WhatsApp sender is now possible through the API. Also what about retrieving the list of WhatsApp senders through the API? Thanks :-)

Comment: Heyoooo! In the mean time I left Twilio, so unfortunately I don't have insights anymore. :)

Comment: Oh ok :-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: twilio evangelists, anyone care to comment on this?  The last update was 50 weeks ago.

Comment: @jboga can you tell me please, how can I do it?

Comment: @JoseAngel last time I checked it was still not possible to set up the webhook URL programmatically for WhatsApp number. In my company we set up the "normal" SMS webhook URL programmatically and then go to the Twilio console to manually copy that URL into the WhatsApp configuration for that phone number.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Twilio now supports programmatically updating the inbound SMS urls.

You can find the resource here on how to do it.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource

Comment: my question is specifically for WhatsApp-capable phone number. Did you try that? Because the URLs for those phone number needs to be updated in a specific place in the UI and this is different from where the URL is updated for non-WhatsApp phone numbers.