# Get webhooks for Twilio number via Twilio API

Tags: twilio-api

Is there a way to find out which webhooks have been set up for a number via the Twilio API? I want to check that my users have set up a webhook correctly. My understanding is that the webhook cannot be set programmatically so it must be done manually. (See [Set webhook for incoming messages on Twilio-Whatsapp phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384707/set-webhook-for-incoming-messages-on-twilio-whatsapp-phone-number))

Answer (score 0):

*Late answer but may help someone looking for the same.*

At the twilio docs for phone numbers api, you can find [Fetch an IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#fetch-an-incomingphonenumber-resource) which describes the fetching API for certain resources associated with that phone number.

Here's a curl code extract from that doc:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/IncomingPhoneNumbers/[SID].json" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```